# Multi image selection from Device gallery in in Cordova Mobile App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have made an hybrid application with cordova > 5.x.x for android.

For One of the functionallity i want to select multiple images from device gallery at once.currently i am using plugin which gives provision to select single image from device gallery.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera

Is there any plugin available to achive above functionallity ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357588/read-all-images-from-gallery-in-ionic-app/39612931#39612931